# Hola, tengo un problema con los sitios web de Laravel dentro de Laragon

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

Luego de crear mi sitio web, cada vez que lo intento abrir, me sale una pestaña de Windows y no la pagina que estoy haciendo, aca les dejo para que lo vean y por favor diganme ¿como puedo solucionarlo?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar un [mcve]. Las imágenes pueden ser muy bonitas, pero no son de utilidad. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.